# Null Pointer Exception on Http Response

Tags: android, android-networking

I am using the following class which is use to connect to the internet for parsing however I am gwtting the NullPointerException on the HTTPResponse. I also added Internet permission on manifest file. Here is my code

```
public class XMLParser {

    public String getXMLfromUrl(String Url){

        String xml =  null;

        try{

                 DefaultHttpClien httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();
                 HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                 final int status = httpRes.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                 if (status != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                     Log.d("meassage", "------------");
                 }

                 HttpEntity httpEnt = httpRes.getEntity();
                 xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEnt);

        }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return xml;
    }

    public Document getDomElement(String xml){

        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory  dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try{

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        }catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }


        return doc;
    }
}
```

Help me to find out where I have done the mistake and suggest require changes. Thanks.
Here is a stack trace

```
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gallery.parsing.madhuri/com.example.gallery.parsing.madhuri.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:496)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at com.example.gallery.parsing.madhuri.XMLParser.getXMLfromUrl(XMLParser.java:37)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at com.example.gallery.parsing.madhuri.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-04 16:58:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2662):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: It would be great if you posted the stack trace as well.

Comment: updated my question with stack trace.

Comment: you havent specified any url for httpPost.

Comment: thats why response is getting null.

Comment: Please don't use tabs for white space when you're posting your code.  I've cleaned it up a bit for you as it was very difficult to read.

Comment: don't you need, like, a URL ?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified any url for httpPost. 
That's why the response is getting null.

It should be initialized as

```
        HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(url);
```

Comment: Ok I done that but now its showing error   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: This is bcoz you are doing network connection on main thread. 
add network connection in worker thread.

Comment: What android version do you use? XMLParser run in own thread or main thread?

Answer (score 1):

Use a AsyncTask to load and parse the data, it will increase performance and you dont get a NetworkOnMainThreadException beacouse AsyncTask is another Thread. Post the code below in your class with your methods (getXmlFromUrl(Url)). To execute you just have to call (maybe on OnCreate()):

```
new YourTask().execute("");
```

Here is the code:

```
    private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
          String xmlContent = "";
           @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... s) {

            //Here you have to make the loading / parsing tasks
            //Don't call any UI actions here. For example a Toast.show() this will couse Exceptions
            // UI stuff you have to make in onPostExecute method
              xmlContent=getXMLfromUrl(YOUR_URL);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // This method will called during doInBackground is in process
            // Here you can for example show a ProgressDialog
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            // onPostExecute is called when doInBackground finished
            // Here you can for example fill your Listview with the content loaded in doInBackground method


                  // here you can process he loading content in doInBackground
                  // for example:


  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), xmlContent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

}
```

Here you can learn more about AsyncTasks:

[AsyncTask developer Guide](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html&ei=XXWvUJivB8XIswajxIDABg&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&sig2=CmICU1zanbO_qVgO4V9uEg)

Answer (score 0):

o specified any url for httpPost

It should be initialized as

```
    HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(url);
```

and Also create async class for them. call them in an asych class